# React - MacOS (M1) - install react-route-dom error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, installation, terminal

While using VScode,
Tried to install react-route-dom through terminal (in VSCode)

I keeps getting this msg instead downloading via terminal:

```
➜  fin_amazonweb git:(master) ✗ sudo install react-router-dom

usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

I don't get it whats wrong with it... s/o can possibly help?

Comment: What are you trying to use to install it, `npm`? It seems like you forgot that part

Answer (score 0):

the correct command is `npm i react-router-dom`